# GL_NO_ERROR when glVertexAttribPointer has no bound buffer

Tags: opengl

I have called `glVertexAttribPointer` without binding `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` [first](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml):

> If pointer is not NULL, a non-zero named buffer object must be bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target (see glBindBuffer), otherwise an error is generated.

I had trouble finding this bug because the error is `GL_NO_ERROR` after calling `glVertexAttribPointer`, but `glGet(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING)` yields 0, so shouldn't this raise this error?

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if zero is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER buffer object binding point and the pointer argument is not NULL.

This failure to yield an error happens when `pointer` is non-null.

Is this a bug in my OpenGL driver? Or am I looking for the error in the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use a [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object), then you've to use a compatibility profile context. 
See [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context).

---

When you use [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) then a named buffer object has to be bound to the `ARRAY_BUFFER` target and the last parameter is treated as a byte offset into this buffer.

In [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf#page=421&zoom=100,0,753) (compatibility context) there is the option to bind a zero named buffer (0). Then the last parameter is a pointer to the buffer data.

But if you use a core profile context, then a named buffer object has to be bound in any case.

---

In the [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf) is specified that

> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated if a non-zero vertex array
>   object is bound, no buffer is bound to ARRAY_BUFFER, and pointer is not
>   NULL.

This means more or less, if you use a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) than you've to use [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object), too. It is not allowed to bind a VAO, bind no VBO and to set a pointer.